# Apply VPN only to routable internet addresses

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, networkmanager

How can I convince NetworkManager that a specific VPN is to be used only for traffic outside the local network, whatever that local network happens to be?

I have an external VPN service that I use to avoid surveillance and censorship, both within organisations (like an employer or a café) and within my home country that mandates our ISPs spy on their behalf.

So when I'm connecting to the various networks my notebook computer finds itself in, I want to connect to that VPN and have all internet traffic go through that VPN.

Simultaneously, any addresses on the local LAN should *not* be routed through that VPN, because those local addresses are not routed outside the local network.

What do I need to do in the NetworkManager VPN configuration, to ensure that when I've enabled that VPN it will apply to internet addresses but not local non-routable LAN addresses?

Bear in mind that those LAN addresses can change dynamically as I move the computer to a different network, yet the VPN configuration should                                                                                                                                                                      remain the same.

Comment: Probably depends on the VPN technology/protocol/client you are using via NetworkManager. Could you clarify that.

Comment: Add the OS in use, and any applicable software in use. (VPN software & version). Please add this information to the question and not the comments. This could be as simple as adding a custom routing table on the host OS.